# updating render when ng-include changes angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular - my issue - when I call `$scope.editProfile()` the value of `panels.left` is changed in the factory but the content on the page does not change.  In the html file I am using ng-include like this:

```
<div ng-include src="leftPanel"></div>
```

When first loading the page views/profile.html is rendered in the div. But later when I call `$scope.editProfile()` I want the div to refresh with the content of views/edit.html - the value does change in the factory (console.log proved it) but the page content does not update.

```
myApp.factory("panels", function () {
    return {
        left: "views/profile.html",
        center: "views/msgs.html",
        right: "views/friends.html"
    };
});

myApp.controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope, api, panels) {
    $scope.leftPanel = panels.left;
    $scope.centerPanel = panels.center;
    $scope.rightPanel = panels.right;
});

myApp.controller("profileCtrl", function ($scope, api, panels) {
    $scope.user = api.bio.get();
    $scope.editProfile = function () {
    panels.left = "views/edit.html";
    };
});
```

Comment: You should use angulars route or state for loading views. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: The views on my page are all wrapped in divs, three different views are on the page at all times - my understanding is that angulars routs and ng-view can only handle a single view at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using named views in [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#multiple--named-views) its a much better way to deal with routing and states than what you have right now.

However if you want your current logic to work you need to wrap a factory assignment in a function in your homeCtrl.

i.e,:

```
$scope.leftPanel = function() { return panel.left; }
```

Comment: Thanks, ui-router looks like a perfect solution, and thanks also for the solution with my current logic.